# How to add a logo to an ERC20 token?

Tags: ethereum, polygon, cryptocurrency, erc20, etherscan

I am new to blockchain. I really couldn't understand how to add logo to my erc20 crypto token on polygon before listing it on any coin market.

[image: I want to add my own custom image to the circular portion]

I want to add my own custom image to the circular portion. How can I change this current logo to something new and If I transfer the token to some other account, my custom logo will be displayed?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetaMask implements the [EIP-747](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-747) standard (currently unfinished in May 2022) and its `wallet_watchAsset` method to display custom token logo.

Mind that this is not a centralized database of logos per token address, so each MetaMask instance can theoretically display a different logo for the same token. And that users need to explicitly add the logo either manually or by confirming a MetaMask popup opened by a snippet from your web app.

Code example from [MetaMask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-your-token.html):

```
const wasAdded = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
    params: {
        type: 'ERC20', // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
        options: {
            address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
            symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
            decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
            image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: So what will happen if I list it on market? What logo will it show there?

Comment: @MuhammadTahmidIslam It depends on the market. For example Uniswap uses logos from Trustwallet ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/UniSwap/comments/km8r8k/how_to_add_logo_to_the_token_in_uniswap/)), so in order to have your token logo on Uniswap you need to add it to the list of [Trustwallet assets](https://github.com/trustwallet/assets) and pay them [Trustwallet] a listing fee... Other markets might have different rules.